When should I include the score benefit of a local decision when using minimax?
In the Stone Game problem, Alice and Bob take turns picking a pile of stones from the start or the end. The goal is to maximize Alice's total
def play(turn, left, right):
    if left > right:
        return 0

    end = piles[right] + play(1 - turn, left, right - 1)
    start = piles[left] + play(1 - turn, left + 1, right)

    return max(start, end) if turn == 0 else min(start, end)

alice = play(0, 0, n - 1)

This follows the classic minimax algorithm.
Let's now take a look at Stone Game II. In this problem, Alice and Bob can pick the next 1 <= x <= 2m piles of stones, where m is the maximum x somebody has used.
To my surprise, classic minimax would return the same number of stones whether it is Alice or Bob's turn, giving us an incorrect final answer
# DOESN'T WORK
def play(left, m, turn):
    if left == n-1:
        return 0

    total = 0
    ans = inf if turn else -inf
    for pos in range(left+1, min(n, left+2*m+1)):
        total += piles[pos]
        value = total + play(pos, max(m, pos - left), 1 - turn)
        if turn == 0:
            ans = max(ans, value)
        else:
            ans = min(ans, value)
    
    return ans

alice = play(-1, 1, 0)

However, if we only include total in Alice's calculation, it suddenly works:
# WORKS
def play(left, m, turn):
    if left == n-1:
        return 0

    total = 0
    ans = inf if turn else -inf
    for pos in range(left+1, min(n, left+2*m+1)):
        total += piles[pos]
        value = play(pos, max(m, pos - left), 1 - turn)
        if turn == 0:
            ans = max(ans, total + value)
        else:
            ans = min(ans, value)
    
    return ans

alice = play(-1, 1, 0)

Could someone explain why we're not supposed to add the local total for the minimizer in the second example?
Here's a discrepancy I noticed that may have something to do with the answer: value is always the same recursive call when we take min/max in the second problem, but in the first problem, end and start are different recursive calls.

Because Alice is maximizing the total, while Bob in minimizing Alice's gain in the second game.

@123 In both cases, alice should equal the max number of stones possible for her to grab. In both games, there is a finite amount of points that will all be split between both players, so I don’t see the difference

The function we're trying to maximize is f := amount of stones alice gets. That's why we only add stones for Alice; the function we're maximizing doesn't include the amount of stones Bob gets.
So then why does the first algorithm work? Turns out it's not generally correct, and only works because this specific problem constrains len(piles) as even, making it so Alice always wins. If we actually look at the values from the first function, it returns the same answer for Bob and Alice too (this was just obfuscated because alice > sum(piles) - alice is always true, so the bug didn't produce wrong answers)
An actually correct minimax implementation for game 1 would look like this:
def play(turn, left):
    right_used = turn - left
    right = n - 1 - right_used

    if left > right:
        return 0

    end = play(turn + 1, left)
    start = play(turn + 1, left + 1)

    return min(start, end) if turn % 2 else max(piles[left] + start, piles[right] + end)


The answer would be obvious if you'd just write a comment before the play function explaining what it's supposed to do, like:
# Given a state of the game board, if turn == 0, return the maximum number
# of stones that Alice can guarantee herself.  If turn == 1, return the
# tightest bound that Bob can apply to the number of stones that *Alice* will get.

In both cases, the function returns a number of stones that Alice gets.  In neither case should you add stones that Bob collects to the returned value.
Aside:  I would write separate functions alice() and bob().  Cramming two functions into one and using a parameter to distinguish makes the interface more difficult to understand.

"In neither case should you add stones that Bob collects to the returned value."
In both minimax and the first algorithm, we add the local value for bob each time

In the first algorithm, piles[right] and piles[left] are equivalent to total

All of the programs in the question, except for the last one, are incorrect.

that is not true, the first algorithm is correct. You can use the link and subtract the function result from sum(piles) to verify

try it with [10,21,10]

It definitely works. Passes the tests when you click the link to the problem

alice = play(0, 0, n - 1);
return alice > sum(piles) - alice

I reread the problem description. Turns out [10,21,10] is an invalid testcase because len(piles) must be even

No, the problem description says that the total number across all piles is odd, so that there's always a winner.  Alec, you are trying really hard not to get this right.  The mistake in your original program always favors Alice, so if you want to see it get the wrong answer, you need to use a test case where Bob wins.

Ah, that may be...  in which case evenreturn true; will pass all tests, but your original program still gives the wrong number of stones for Alice.

Constraint number 2 is that len(piles) is even. This allows Alice to always win.
But I think you're actually onto something. Maybe the first code works only because of the arbitrary problem restriction. But isn't that actually the classic definition of minimax?
(convo is out of order because I deleted and put back this comment lol, this one should be btwn your 2)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Pseudocode
there's no distinction between the minimizer and maximizer here

There are ways to define a problem so that min vs max is the only difference, but you didn't define the problem that way.  It goes back to writing that comment before the function that says what exactly it's supposed to do.

So the general rule in minimax is only add local result for the maximizer?
Is there a way to define this problem so min vs max is the only difference?

OHH, ok I get it now. the function we are trying to maximize is f := amount of stones alice gets. therefore we are just running min/max on that specific function, which doesnt include the amount of stones bob gets

Yes, that's right.
